# Replace master branch with new forked branch

Tags: git, github, branch, github-pages, git-fork

I forked a repo that I own to make some changes to the gh-pages branch.  I ended up creating a new one from scratch so now it does not share commit history with the original.

I now want to merge this new gh-pages branch back to the original repo, replacing the original gh-pages branch.

When I try to compare and create a pull request, I get this error on github.

```
Forked_Repo:gh-pages and Original_Repo:gh-pages are entirely different commit histories.
```

How should I go about replacing the gh-pages on my original repo with the new version on the fork?

Comment: How many of the project's files did you modify?

Comment: On the gh-pages branch I basically deleted everything and started fresh so that the html files are separate from the project files.

Comment: If you are dealing with all new files, then why don't you just `git add` them to a branch of the original project and push?

Comment: Because the new branch is completely independent of the existing branches.  All of the content that is on the current branches should not be included on the gh-pages branch and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the branch `gh-pages` on original repo and then push the new `gh-pages` to it.

In the folk repo, you set original repo as a remote:

```
git remote add upstream <original-repo-url>
```

And then push `gh-pages` to `upstream`:

```
git push -f upstream gh-pages
```

Edited: add detail command to push branch from fork to origin

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I do that from the fork?  Do I have to set upstream to the original repo first to be able to push to it?

Comment: In the folk repo, you set original repo as a remote:

    `git remote add upstream <original-repo-url>`

And then push `gh-pages` to `upstream`:

    `git push -f upstream gh-pages`

Comment: This description is probably worth including in the above.  I will give you points for it anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked brilliantly btw.  I was really nervous about deleting an entire branch like this and relieved when it went well.  :)